# ncss query - polygon instead of lat long box

Tags: thredds

I'm curious if there is a way to query the NDFD or other layers in the thredds server with a customized polygon instead of a rectangular lat long box?  Thanks!

--Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The work-around would be to make a request for the box that bounds your polygon of interest, then do the subset to the polygon locally. Depending on what tools you are using, there may be libraries out there to help you do it. Failing that, the [math to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) is not too awful.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll likely approximate the catchment polygons to rectangles.